# How can I make my formula fit properly in a 2 column page latex document?

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

I tried using naively the align instruction but it doesn't seem to work properly. Is there any way to fit it without splitting it?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

${f}_{v+1, v}\left(N_{0}, N_{1}, \ldots, N_{m}\right)= \begin{cases}0, & \text { if }\left(N_{0}, N_{1}, \ldots, N_{m}\right)=(0,0, \ldots, 0) ; \\ +\infty, & \text { otherwise. }\end{cases}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: you ask about errors from `align` in a two column document, but post an example of inline math in a single columnt document. You could make the example more relevant to the question,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want `multline` rather than `align` as it's a single long expression not two expressions with alignment points, also it takes less space.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{multline*}
  {f}_{v+1, v}(N_{0}, N_{1}, \ldots, N_{m})\\
 = \begin{cases}0, & \text { if }(N_{0}, N_{1}, \ldots, N_{m})=(0,0, \ldots, 0) ; \\
       +\infty, & \text { otherwise. }\end{cases}
\end{multline*}
\noindent X\dotfill X

\noindent X\dotfill X

\noindent X\dotfill X
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, When I tried it in my document the equation was still not properly adjusted.

Comment: @Rte well that is not surprising as you asked to make something fit in a space without giving any information about how big the thing is (what fonts and fontsizes you are using)  or how big the space is (the page size)  so all I can do is show general guidelines. You should always include a test document in any question. However,  you may have to adjust more to  make it fit. You can get rid of `(N_{0}, N_{1}, \ldots, N_{m})=(0,0, \ldots, 0)` which is pointlessly verbose for a narrow column and write something more compact such as `$N_i=0$ for all $i$`